LaTeX and images
I was wondering if there was an expert in the LaTeX language who could give me some advice on how to quickly insert images into my notes. My goal is to write notes for high schools in which I will talk about limits, derivatives, integrals etc... and I would like to add images, graphs and diagrams useful for understanding the theoretical concepts. I already have everything written by hand and I wanted to digitize it, but I have this problem. The desire to digitize was born from the fact that there is no comparison in terms of quality and the files are significantly smaller in size than the notes I wrote with the iPad and are therefore also much more convenient to manage and share. Any suggestions are warmly welcomed.
The following is a screenshot of my notes to understand better what I want to digitize.
 

Look for package graphicx https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx?lang=en

Thanks, I'll take a look.

If you scan your drawings into PNG, JPG, or PDF you can insert any image file using the graphicx package and the \includegraphics command.  Don't insert them within a figure environment, because you're likely to not want them to float.

Thanks, It's seems to be the faster way.

LaTeX is not for doing things quickly unless you are versed, sorry. ;-). In the long run, however, for illustrating maths packages TikZ/pgf, pgfplots, pstricks/pdftricks and probably the program Gnuplot might be of interest.

If you add one page of your handwritten script, it will be easier to give suggestions how to orocess it.

Yes ok, I done it!!

If you have no experience with LaTeX, my suggestion is start using LyX as the front end. From here you can see how your own examples are exported to LaTeX and pass to edit raw code directly when you understand the basic structure of LaTeX documents (but read some tutorials first will help a lot for this step).

If you have a graphics calculator, you can upload the screen images to your computer.  OTOH, they look awful (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/slides/calculator.pdf).

For high quality but minimal size plots forget  PNG or JPG images and search to save vectorial images as PDF. Use LaTeX is a hard possibility. One  easier draw at hand with Inskcape. Maybe in the the middle use R (example), Python, Gnuplot or other software with output in vectorial formats. The cost/benefit of each option could be very different and depends a lot on the amount and type of graphs. For a few similar graphs, I will use Inkscape, for a bulk of plots, I will search for a programming language.

Here is one way to digitize your example. This way you‘ll always have a document to work with, while the more rudimentary parts disappear over time.
Phase 1: lazyness

use a bitmap tool to split into text and image part
\includegraphics for text, and for image
compile and you‘ll have a rudimentary script
perhaps you enter more regular text, as digitizing progresses

Phase 2: next simple conversion
Probably the text, i.e. the formulas, is also no big deal. You may want to convert such images to Latex for several pages in one go (focus, which increases speed)
Phase 3: more time consuming parts
Though the drawings are simple, it can take some time to code them.

Code for Phase 1
Can't be simpler: just include each (split) image.
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
 \section{Phase 1: lazyness}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{math}   % looks for math.png
 \bigskip
 \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{func} % looks for func.png

Code for Phase 2
Elaborates the formula, leaves the function-drawings as-is/as-are. Please note that I'm not that fluent with amsmath, and ther may be better typesetting solutions.
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
 \begin{multline}
    \lim\displaylimits_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = \pm\infty\\  
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: x \in B_s(\pm\infty) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_r(\pm\infty)\\
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: 
        \begin{cases}
            x >s\quad\Rightarrow f(x)>r\\
            x<-s\ \Rightarrow f(x)<-r
        \end{cases}         
 \end{multline}

Code for Phase 3
First task is to include a mix of drawings, both pdf (vector/Tikz) and png.
\usepackage{subcaption}
...
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}% looks for fig1.pdf
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f2}% looks for f2.png
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = +\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
 
   \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3}% looks for fig3.pdf
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = -\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f4}% looks for f4.png
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
 
  \caption{The four cases, mixed}
 \end{figure}

The second task is to create the cunftional drawings e.g. with Tikz. Here the code for the first one:

class standalone, compiled separately
\nodes contain {text} and are anchored at the center; changing anchors makes positioning much easier
f(x) is just a straight line with a bend, where the -- is replaced by to [in=,out=] and the angles

The intersections need a bit more effort:

tikzlibrary intersections
named pathes
draw an invisible vertical to get intersection-1
draw the colored line and labeling nodes


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,intersections}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},        % nicer arrow tip
 ]
    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[anchor=west]{$f(x)$};
    
    % ~~~ f(x) and intersections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[name path=f] (-.5,.5) to [out=5,in=240] (4,3.5);
    %     r,s
    \draw[name path=s,draw=none]            (2,0) coordinate(S) -- +(0,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=f and s}]  (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
    \draw[teal]           (S)   node[anchor=north]{$s$} -- (intersection-1) -- 
                        +(-2,0) node[anchor=east]{$r$};
    %    f(x),x
    \draw[name path=fx,draw=none]           (3,0) coordinate(F) -- +(0,4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=f and fx}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
    \draw[magenta,dashed] (F)   node[anchor=north]{$x$} -- (intersection-1) -- 
                        +(-3,0) node[anchor=east]{$f(x)$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Figure 3 is similar, with some minor adaptations:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,intersections}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},        % nicer arrow tip
 ]
    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,1) node[anchor=west]{$f(x)$};
    
    % ~~~ f(x) and intersections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[name path=f] (-.5,.5) to [out=-5,in=100] (4,-3.5);
    %     r,s
    \draw[name path=s,draw=none]            (2,0) coordinate(S) -- +(0,-4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=f and s}]  (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
    \draw[teal]           (S)   node[anchor=south]{$s$} -- (intersection-1) -- 
                        +(-2,0) node[anchor=east]{$-r$};
    %    f(x),x
    \draw[name path=fx,draw=none]           (3,0) coordinate(F) -- +(0,-4);
    \fill[name intersections={of=f and fx}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
    \draw[magenta,dashed] (F)   node[anchor=south]{$x$} -- (intersection-1) -- 
                        +(-3,0) node[anchor=east]{$f(x)$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


All steps in one document:

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents % uncomment and compile twice for a TOC
 This code demonstrates the 3 phases of converting a manual transcript into \LaTeX.
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Phase 1: lazyness}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{math}   % looks for math.png
 \bigskip
 \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{func} % looks for func.png
 \clearpage
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Phase 2: next simple conversion}
 \begin{multline}
    \lim\displaylimits_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = \pm\infty\\  
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: x \in B_s(\pm\infty) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_r(\pm\infty)\\
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: 
        \begin{cases}
            x >s\quad\Rightarrow f(x)>r\\
            x<-s\ \Rightarrow f(x)<-r
        \end{cases}         
 \end{multline}

 \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{func} % looks for func.png

 \clearpage
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Phase 3: more time consuming parts}
 \begin{multline}
    \lim\displaylimits_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = \pm\infty\\  
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: x \in B_s(\pm\infty) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_r(\pm\infty)\\
    \Rightarrow\forall r > 0 \quad \exists s>0: 
        \begin{cases}
            x >s\quad\Rightarrow f(x)>r\\
            x<-s\ \Rightarrow f(x)<-r
        \end{cases}         
 \end{multline}
 

 \begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}% looks for fig1.pdf
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f2}% looks for f2.png
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = +\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
 
   \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3}% looks for fig3.pdf
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = -\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f4}% looks for f4.png
    \caption{$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$}
  \end{subfigure}
 
  \caption{The four cases, mixed}
 \end{figure}
 
\end{document}


I believe \includegraphics has a clip option.  Using that would allow OP to keep using the already scanned image without needing to rescan.  But it would require lots of fiddling to get the clip numbers just right.

@Teepeemm, it has, starting at page 9 in https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf . However, your gain is minimal, if at all, when you have to adapt those coordinates from scan to scan. In the end it's a matter of preference. The way put here is consistent with the process described first. In the end you want replacement by Tikz, pstricks etc.

If you scan your drawings into PNG, JPG, or PDF you can insert any image file using the graphicx package and the \includegraphics command. Don't insert them within a figure environment, because you're likely to not want them to float.

[Nadolig llawen.]

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{center}

Some more text.
\end{document}

LaTeX can be faster when you know it well, but it is not faster during the significant time it takes to learn.
Drawing generic diagrams and illustrations in LaTeX - as opposed to drawing them in some other programme and using \includegraphics{} as above - is basically never faster, as far as I can tell. Or perhaps I have just never managed to learn this part.
Drawing specific kinds of diagrams or illustrations can be faster, but you have to know specific packages well, in addition to knowing LaTeX.
So if a significant reason for wanting to use LaTeX for your notes is speed, you would be better advised to follow a different path ....
